# c++ struct type redefinition error

Tags: c++, struct, header-files

I'm working on a simple game C++ game using the SFML library. This is one of my first endeavors with C++ and I'm running into some problems with defining structs in headers.

Here is the bullet.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

struct BulletTransform {
    sf::RectangleShape shape;
    //details
    BulletTransform(float, float);
};

class Bullet {
//class definition stuff, no problems here
```

then I try to create an implementation in the bullet.cpp file:

```
#include "Bullet.h"

struct BulletTransform {

    sf::RectangleShape shape;
    BulletTransform::BulletTransform(float mX, float mY)
    {
        //constructor for shape stuff
    }
};
```

Now when I try to compile it throws an error saying struct in the bullet.cpp being a type redefinition. I understand that I cannot define a struct with the same name twice, but I am also not sure how I can fix this issue. Do I somehow need to get a reference to the definition in the header? Or is my implementation simply wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like all you need to do is implement `BulletTransform::BulletTransform(float mX, float mY)` You don't need to redefine the structure to do that.

Comment: `struct BulletTransform { ...` has no business being in both the header and the cpp file. the latter includes the former; that should be sufficient.

Comment: *I'm working on a simple game C++ game* -- Problem is that C++ is not a simple language.  If you're making basic errors such as this, then maybe take a step back and learn how to use the constructs properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the header file you can make the declaration. In the source file the definition - thats the rule of thumb in general. In your case for example:

in bullet.h:

```
struct BulletTransform {
    sf::RectangleShape shape;

    // cntr
    BulletTransform(float mX, float mY) ;

    // other methods
    void Function1(float x, float y, float z);


};
```

in bullet.cpp:

```
BulletTransform::BulletTransform(float mX, float mY) {
  // here goes the constructor stuff
}

void BulletTransform::Function1(float x, float y, float z) {
// ... implementation details
}
```

Normally you don't do some heavy stuff in the constructor - just the  initialization of data members for example to some default values. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all who responded! I was misunderstanding the way you should implement structs from a header and its syntax. It works now!

Answer (score 2):

You've repeated your struct definition in your implemenation file. Don't do that. Instead, provide definitions for the individual members, like this:

```
#include "Bullet.h"


BulletTransform::BulletTransform(float mX, float mY)
{
    //constructor for shape stuff
}
```

Comment: Why would you redefine the non-static member `shape`?

Comment: My bad. Fixed it now.